# Potential null reference when assigning error to pointer pointer of error

Tags: objective-c, c

Getting this on the `*perror = error` line. Even when I wrap it in `if (error)`

```
- (BOOL)validate:(NSError **)perror password:(BOOL)password {
    BOOL ret = YES;

    NSMutableString * errorMessage = [@"" mutableCopy];

    ...other validation code

    NSError * error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"Profile" code:100 userInfo:dictionary];

    if (error) {
       *perror = error;
    }

    return  ret;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's possible that `perror` could be `nil`. Guard against that:

```
if (error && perror) {
    *perror = error;
}
```